# Modifying/optimising for loop in R to get faster results

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the dataset with around 3 mln. lines and I want to calculate the difference of the value between next and previous line, but the R is running for a really long time when we have so many lines.

```
nrow <- nrow(data_bitstamp)
for (i in 2:nrow) {
  data_bitstamp$diff[i] <- difftime(data_bitstamp$arb[i], data_bitstamp$arb[i-1])}
```

This was running for an hour and still no results. Maybe there is a modification, which could be used to get the result faster.

Comment: You don't need a loop at all here. `difftime` is vectorized, like many R functions, so the single line `data_bitstamp$diff <- c(difftime(data_bitstamp$arb), NA)` should give you the correct result and will be much faster.

Comment: This works  `data_bitstamp$diff <- difftime(data_bitstamp$arb, lag(data_bitstamp$arb))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `lag` function to create a list that you can use as an argument to the `difftime` function as shown below. I also created a data frame and added some timing code.

```
# make a 10 million row data frame
data_bitstamp = data.frame('arb' = rep(Sys.time(), 10000000))
starttheclock = Sys.time() # timing start

lag_arb = lag(data_bitstamp$arb) 
data_bitstamp$diff = difftime(data_bitstamp$arb, lag_arb)

stoptheclock = Sys.time()  # timing end
elapsed = stoptheclock - starttheclock
elapsed
# Time difference of 0.8299184 secs
```

The `lag` and `difftime` could be done in a single line but for clarity I showed them separately.

Comment: Thank so much! It was really quick and with good result.